# Open datasets for educational use

Tags: data-request, education

I'm interested in compiling open datasets for educational use. For example, [this page from the State University of New York Geneseo](http://libguides.geneseo.edu/data) includes open datasets by topic.

I'm especially interesting in datasets that may be appropriate for K-12 use, so I think it is important the data are a) cleaned and b) possibly relevant / interesting. **Are there other sites, repositories, or resources with open data sets for educational use?**

Comment: I wrote a blog post with resources including the resource described in the answer: http://jmichaelrosenberg.com/blog/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quandl has open datasets. There are many that are free and although Quandl's focus is financial and economic data, there's also data on Countries, Society, Demography, Energy and Education. I hope they'll be useful for K-12 learning. You can browse Quandl's collections here: https://www.quandl.com/collections When you click on a collection, the articles written are meant to be educational for readers. Also, the sources of open, free data on Quandl are listed here: https://www.quandl.com/blog/free-data-on-quandl They include sources like the United Nations, World Bank, World Health Organization and many more. Hope this helps! [Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Answer (score 4):

Here are some useful data sources & repositories:

https://data.sfgov.org/data

https://data.fivethirtyeight.com

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html

https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/data

https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets

Comment: Added these to the above-referenced post (http://jmichaelrosenberg.com/open-datasets-for-educational-use/)